# VBA How to perform a input validation?

Tags: excel, vba

This is the code I tried which is not working. When users do not enter anything or enter the wrong orderID, the cell after the last orderID will turns yellow and add text "Delivering" in `offset(0,6)cell`.

```vb
Sub Accept()
    
    Sheets("Deliver").Select
    Dim inputID As String
    inputID = InputBox("Enter order ID")
    Dim orderID As Range
    Set orderID = Range("B:B").Find(what:=inputID, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)
    If orderID Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Not orderID Is Nothing Then
        orderID.Interior.Color = vbYellow
        orderID.Offset(0, 6).Value = "Delivering"
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Make additional check `inputID = ""`. Remove duplicated check `orderID Is Nothing`. BTW I can't reproduce the described case when I enter the wrong not empty orderID.